# Finding $\small{\min\limits_{a+b+c=1}P=\sqrt{2a^3+abc}+\sqrt{2b^3+abc}+\sqrt{2c^3+abc}. }$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c=1.$ Find the minimum of $P$ $$\color{black} {P=\sqrt{2a^3+abc}+\sqrt{2b^3+abc}+\sqrt{2c^3+abc}. }$$
By $a=b=c=1/3$ we get $P=1.$

Thus, I used AM-GM inequality $$a^3+a^3+abc\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a^7bc}\implies \sqrt{2a^3+abc}\ge \sqrt[6]{27a^7bc} $$
The rest is prove $$\sqrt[6]{27a^7bc}+\sqrt[6]{27b^7ac}+\sqrt[6]{27c^7ba}\ge 1.$$
But I don't know how to prove the last inequality.

Hope you help me prove it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your last inequality is wrong when $abc=0.$

Answer (score 1):

By Holder
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2a^3+abc}\right)^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}\geq(a+b+c)^3$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}\leq1,$$ which is true by C-S.